# Attribute does not render after save model on grid

Tags: extjs

I am using Ext Js in my application and I have a problem. After I saved a new model, the grid should renderer automatically columns, however after the save the attribute 'id', which is one of columns does not renderer, I need to refresh the page to the data appear in my grid,  can anyone provide a insight ??
The first column is 'id', before refresh.

[image]

After refresh the page:

[image]

Initial grid config:

```
Ext.define('GridConfiguracao', {
extend : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
store : 'ConfiguracaoStore',
features: [{
    groupHeaderTpl: 'Estado: {name}',
    ftype: 'groupingsummary',
}],
listeners : {
    render : function(grid) {
        grid.store.load();
    }
},
title: 'Configurações',
columns : [{
    header : 'ID',
    dataIndex : 'id',
    flex : 0.2,
    summaryType: 'count',
    summaryRenderer: function(value){
        return Ext.String.format('{0} {1}', value, value !== 1 ? 'configurações' : 'configuração');

    }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods you can do.

First method, get the store of the grid and reload the store.

```
myGrid.getStore().reload();
```

Second, get the view of the grid and refresh.

```
myGrid.getView().refresh();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I solved my problem with your sugestion !!